# Django & intercooler.js : Pass a variable to a view with Intercooler.js

Tags: django, intercooler.js

I am trying to integrate intercooler.js (https://intercoolerjs.org) to my project but failing at passing a variable from the template into a view.

Using the code below, I am trying to display an integer incrementing by 1 on each click.

(a) the template:

```
<form id="defaults">
  <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
</form>
<button ic-post-to="{% url 'habitap:click' %}?click_value={{clicks}}" ic-include="#defaults">
{{clicks}}
</button>
```

(b) the view

```
def click(request):

    clicks = request.POST.get('click_value', 0)
    clicks = clicks + 1
    context = {'clicks': clicks}

    template = Template("{{clicks}}")
    request_context = RequestContext(request, context)


    return HttpResponse(template.render(request_context))
```

Thank you !

Comment: Are we supposed to guess _how_ it "fails" ?

Comment: good point apologies, I will detail that in the question

Comment: Why not store and increment clicks in js? On the intercooler.js home page they have an example of this. If you're going to do it in django, you need to store the clicks value as an input on the form so it's sent to the view.

Comment: ok i will try that. I was curious to see if there was a way to do this without js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :) :) :)

the template:

```
<form id="defaults">
  <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
</form>
<button ic-post-to="{% url 'habitap:click' %}?click={{click}}" ic-replace-target="true" ic-include="#defaults">Update Div</button>
```

the view:

```
def click(request):

    click = int('0' + request.GET.get('click', 0))
    click = click + 1

    template = Template(
        '''
        <button ic-post-to="{% url 'habitap:click' %}?click={{click}}" ic-replace-target="true" ic-include="#defaults">
        {{click}}
        </div>
        ''')
    context = {'click': click}
    request_context = RequestContext(request, context)

    return HttpResponse(template.render(request_context))
```